# Is my FTP server being scanned/probed by hackers?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I just recently did a bunch of research on how to set up an FTP server (VSFTPD 3.0.5) and secure it to the point that I feel reasonably comfortable running it out of my closet and exposing it to the internet from my home network to share with a select few individuals.

I've had the server running and exposed to the internet for all of about 36 hours now (eyes trained closely on the connection logs) and already I've noticed at least two separate occasions where I can see what appears to be a handful of unknown IPs *trying* (unsuccessfully from all indications known to me) to log in, or maybe just fuzz the FTP login prompt with garbage hoping to break it somehow? I can't really make sense of what they're doing here, if in fact it is a bad actor.  Here's a sample of the server logs:

```
Sat Jan  6 15:27:02 2024 [pid 1553282] CONNECT: Client "199.45.154.16"
Sat Jan  6 15:27:02 2024 [pid 1553282] FTP response: Client "199.45.154.16", "220 Take a file, leave a file."
Sat Jan  6 15:27:02 2024 [pid 1553282] FTP command: Client "199.45.154.16", "????????????!??#?_??NV????ZBV??M??R???E??MU l?"??w??s??]#????Y??w??""
Sat Jan  6 15:27:02 2024 [pid 1553282] FTP response: Client "199.45.154.16", "530 Please login with USER and PASS."
Sat Jan  6 15:27:02 2024 [pid 1553282] FTP command: Client "199.45.154.16"
Sat Jan  6 15:27:02 2024 [pid 1553282] FTP command: Client "199.45.154.16", "G??XP??????3?G???????9?K???????E?????????????#?????+?"
Sat Jan  6 15:27:02 2024 [pid 1553282] FTP response: Client "199.45.154.16", "530 Please login with USER and PASS."
Sat Jan  6 15:27:02 2024 [pid 1553282] FTP command: Client "199.45.154.16", "?$?????,?R?S???????????????'?/???(?0?`?A?V?W?????????????"
Sat Jan  6 15:27:02 2024 [pid 1553282] FTP response: Client "199.45.154.16", "530 Please login with USER and PASS."
Sat Jan  6 15:27:02 2024 [pid 1553282] FTP command: Client "199.45.154.16", "?/?<???????5?=???????A?????????????????????????<MY_HOME_IP>???????????????"
Sat Jan  6 15:27:02 2024 [pid 1553282] FTP response: Client "199.45.154.16", "530 Please login with USER and PASS."
Sat Jan  6 15:27:02 2024 [pid 1553282] FTP command: Client "199.45.154.16", "?"
Sat Jan  6 15:27:02 2024 [pid 1553282] FTP response: Client "199.45.154.16", "530 Please login with USER and PASS."
Sat Jan  6 15:27:03 2024 [pid 1553286] CONNECT: Client "199.45.154.16"
Sat Jan  6 15:27:03 2024 [pid 1553286] FTP response: Client "199.45.154.16", "220 Take a file, leave a file."
Sat Jan  6 15:27:03 2024 [pid 1553286] FTP command: Client "199.45.154.16", "??????????????F?Z?0????YE???L[7I?IQ?]Q????] ?A?3????!"1?h#u??u?K?m????xU?G?????????????????A???????=?5???????<?/?"
Sat Jan  6 15:27:03 2024 [pid 1553286] FTP response: Client "199.45.154.16", "530 Please login with USER and PASS."
Sat Jan  6 15:27:03 2024 [pid 1553286] FTP command: Client "199.45.154.16", "?????????????W?V?A?`?0?(???/?'???????????????S?R?,?????$?"
Sat Jan  6 15:27:03 2024 [pid 1553286] FTP response: Client "199.45.154.16", "530 Please login with USER and PASS."
Sat Jan  6 15:27:03 2024 [pid 1553286] FTP command: Client "199.45.154.16", "?+?????#?????????????E???????K?9???????G?3???????????????<MY_HOME_IP>???????????????"
Sat Jan  6 15:27:03 2024 [pid 1553286] FTP response: Client "199.45.154.16", "530 Please login with USER and PASS."
Sat Jan  6 15:27:03 2024 [pid 1553286] FTP command: Client "199.45.154.16", "?"
Sat Jan  6 15:27:03 2024 [pid 1553286] FTP response: Client "199.45.154.16", "530 Please login with USER and PASS."
```

They just keep doing stuff like this, or trying to log in as `anonymous` which I've disabled.  I've noticed the timestamps on these are so close together, that I'm sure this has to be some kind of automation/script. AI suggested the "commands" could be encrypted or otherwise obfuscated somehow, but I think not, because if I log in and send legitimate commands, VSFTPD logs them clearly in plain text.

I'm thinking that somebody's probing for an exploit in an old version of the server? I've read there was a big issue with VSFTPD 2.3.4, so maybe this is how that exploit was done?

I'm shocked how quickly this server running on my IP was found, and trying to confirm what's happening and whether there's something proactive I can do to stay secure to it (besides pull the server offline).  VSFTPD is not currently locked down by source IP, although I'm considering that now.  I also read something about people using `fail2ban` on their FTP server as well? I've never used it but if that would help I'm interested.

Comment: Password based authentication for a home server, is a recipe for disaster, if that server can reach any other machine on the network. OpenSSH file transfers, with key authentication enabled and password authentication, seems like a safer solution. There is a reason alternatives like Passkey is happening. ChatGPT is irrelevant you should remove any reference to it.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the comment!  I think I agree from an authN security perspective, but using SFTP instead of FTPS seemed like the wrong tool for the job in my case, since I think SFTP by definition requires allowing users to actually have access to interactively log in doesn’t it? I have no need for that so I assumed I’d not even go there.  Agree wrt ChatGPT, I’ll remove it.

Comment: Port hiding, also known as security by obfuscation, is not the best way to handle security, however it does help against some automated probes. In reality, you must use a combination of methods to protect your server. Fail2Ban is super recommended. You can configure it to block attackers after a certain number of failed attempts, for a set period. Other things are to only permit SFTP connections (not FTP), disable weak ciphers, allow TLS1.2 or higher, server selected ciphers, disable anonymous and root logins. Hope all that helps!

Comment: To address your comment: no, SFTP does not mean a user must be able to log in interactively. Check for example `ForceCommand` in OpenSSH. Locking users to a certain directory is harder though, IIRC.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek, why did you down-vote my answer and delete it?... It "fundamentally answers the question" and merely references another user's comment to give credit and provide context.

Comment: downvote, no. Move it into the question cause its useful info but not quite an answer - well yes.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek Ok, sorry about that.  Just so that I understand your perspective and maybe do this better next time, what does an answer to this look like to you?    From my perspective as OP, the key question (right in the title)  are answered in the answer I posted, exactly how I hoped somebody else would.  It decidedly identifies log activity as not a hacking/fuzzing attempt, complete with supplementary info from myself and others in this thread about what it actually is.

Comment: there's no threads here. There's questions and answers. I moved relevant information into your question so someone else with the same issue can find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Most likely, no, this is not a scan/probe attempt by hackers:**

Skimming through the logged source IPs and doing reverse DNS lookups on them (e.g. `dig -x ip.addr.goes.here`), reveals that *most* of the IPs resolved back to hosts that seem to be part of large scanner networks operated by legitimate projects chartered to scan the internet for things that are running and exposed, identify whether they're vulnerable to certain exploits, and (allegedly) notify the owners if possible.

Most of this activity is most likely benign, but keeping an eye on where it's coming from is a good idea.

Some of the sources that I've identified so far are:

- http://scan-55a.shadowserver.org/
- Various nodes owned by https://stretchoid.com/
- Various nodes owned by https://about.censys.io/

**There are additional proactive measures available to prevent malicious activity:**

- Install `fail2ban` - blocks suspected attackers after a configured number of failed login attempts

Answer (score 4):

Every IP on the internet is scanned more or less frequently.

Try to hide as much as possible, by using a non-standard port on the
internet-facing router, and port-forwarding it from this port to
the right port of the computer.

Use also a nice and complicated password for the account that you wish
to expose to the internet.

Comment: non standard ports don't really work. Its so 'cheap' to scan ports even non standard ports get scanned.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Yes, but a standard FTP port can be targeted with attacks that are more specific.

Answer (score 2):

I get a 1000/day on random known ports easily and that is with IP address blocking (but it still records the attempt)

I like to think of this as background radiation,  there are tons of automated bots some are run by hackers and some by security firms.  It is likely the longer it is exposed the greater number of attempts will occur.

A VPN in front of your network would definitely be a better choice than direct exposure.

You should install fail2ban, then in the /etc/fail2ban folder there's a information on how to configure the jail.local and/or jail.conf file to monitor the services you are running.

If you continue direct exposure you will eventually attract the notice of hackers who will try to exploit your FTP server.  As you as a new version is released you will need to update it as hackers read the release notes too.

Mostly you will be exposed to automated tools that will try to guess the password or exploit vsftpd.

As far as blocking IPs goes it would be better to whitelist IP addresses than blocking because your list will quickly expand.  I have been monitoring mainly to satisfy my curiosity, but the result is a block list with 1.1 million permanently blocked IPs.

Comment: How effective would you say IP whitelisting is at preventing exploitation?  (Understanding that it does nothing to harden vsftpd itself, only make me harder to find I guess, but if you consider discovery the first prerequisite to exploitation…) A VPN totally makes sense, but it also adds another barrier to entry for less technical folk.  Finding that balance is tough.

Comment: Depends on how small the whitelist, the more you let in the more risk you expose yourself.  Whitelisting prevents them from even reaching your server to attack it.  However, you will need to have to have entries for you cell phone carriers and wifi and more.  Say you goto a hotel, well their wifi won't be on the whitelist so no entry for you.  Even changing cities when going on vacation or erc travel will likely put you on a non-whitelisted IP..  This is where having a VPN really helps because they can't even see your FTP server without logging in first.